# How can I stack background images on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, background-image

The website has different sections, each section with a different background colour. I want to put the lower edge of the first background-image on top of the upper edge of the second image ([this is the website with the different backgrounds for every section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqngL.png).

/CSS/

```
.welcome {
background-image: url("Welcome_Background.svg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

.about {
background-image: url("About_Background.svg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

This is the CSS for the first two sections.

How do I do that?

Comment: Could you check this [Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)

Comment: Please check this ref : https://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/